# how to define log4j.properties for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, logging, log4j, wowza, appender

I have been using Wowza Stream Engine for content streaming and actually used MySQL for storing logs coming from wowza streaming with the help of log4j MySQL definitions. Before using MySQL, I utilised from the instructions in official wowza web site. The link is below:
https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?130-How-to-log-to-a-mySQL-database

However, because of the fact that MySQL became slower day to day, (sometimes even crashing) while wowza streaming logs coming and accumulating on DB (millions) ; I intended to move the DB Log system to MongoDB. In accordance with this, I used below log4j mongodb statements in order to work it just like in the MySQL DB.

```
log4j.appender.MongoDB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.MongoDB= com.mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver
log4j.appender.MongoDB.hostname=localhost
log4j.appender.MongoDB.port= 27017

log4j.appender.MongoDB.Driver=org.mongodb.mongodb-driver

log4j.appender.MongoDB=org.log4mongo.MongoDbAppender
log4j.appender.MongoDB.databaseName=primarydb
log4j.appender.MongoDB.collectionName=wowza_log
log4j.appender.MongoDB.layout=org.log4mongo.MongoDbPatternLayout

log4j.appender.MongoDB=primarydb.wowza_log.insert({server_ip= {server_ip}, date= {date}, time= {time}, ...}
```

Moreover, needed MongoDB setup and Service setup processes have also been accomplished correctly.

Consequently, I have set up RoboMongo so as to see and observe the collection ('wowza_log') created by wowza streaming. However, after starting a sample mp3 with wowza, the connection seems to be set, but there are no collection named wowza_log created, nothing happens in MongoDB as I see from RoboMongo. I got stuck at this point and wondered if there are some people who can help me to get rid of this problem.